# Geometrical interpretation of second order difference

Tags: real-analysis

If $f$ is a real-valued function which is smooth enough, then we have that

$$f''(x)=\lim_{\Delta x\to 0} \frac{f(x+\Delta x)+f(x-\Delta x) -2f(x)  }{(\Delta x)^2}$$

Hence if $\Delta x$ is very close to $0$, $f''(x)\approx \frac{f(x+\Delta x)+f(x-\Delta x) -2f(x)  }{(\Delta x)^2}$.

My main concern is to understand the quotient $\frac{f(x+\Delta x)+f(x-\Delta x) -2f(x)  }{(\Delta x)^2}$ and then relate it to the usual interpretation of the second derivative.  In other words, I am assuming I don't know anything about derivatives and I want to conclude that the quotient above represents the usual interpretation of the second derivative (concavity, rate of change of slopes).

With that in mind, two questions about it:

1. what is the geometrical interpretation of the quotient $\frac{f(x+\Delta x)+f(x-\Delta x) -2f(x)  }{(\Delta x)^2}$?
2. how is this geometrical interpretation related to the rate of change of slopes?

Some comments:

- I guess from $1$ I should be able to realize a geometrical interpretation of $(\Delta x)^2$.   I tried to relate the latter with something about areas but I have gotten nothing succesful.
- About comment above and question 1:  I can rewrite the quotient to get $2\bigg(\frac{\frac{f(x+\Delta x)+f(x-\Delta x)}{2} -f(x)  }{(\Delta x)^2} \bigg)$.  Then, the numerator tells me how $f(x)$ compares to the average of the images from points nearby, so the second derivative is related to that; HOWEVER, what does $(\Delta x)^2$ mean?

Please note that my question is in terms of some geometrical interpretation, so I don't want to use anything related to Taylor series as an argument (at least, explicitly)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Write the quotient as $$\frac{\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}-\frac{f(xx)-f(x-h)}{h}}{h}$$

Answer (score 1):

Say you have three points $\left(x-\Delta x , f(x-\Delta x)\right) , \left(x , f(x)\right) , \left(x+\Delta x , f(x+\Delta x)\right)$

1. What is the slope of a line connecting the first two points? How about the last two points?
2. What is the difference between the second and the first line’s slope?
3. What is the difference between slopes, divided by the change in abscissa ($\Delta x$)?
4. As $\Delta x \rightarrow 0$, do the line approach tangent line of the function $f(x)$?

Hope that gives you overview of their geometric interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

A more productive rearrangement of the expression would be
$$\lim_{\Delta x\rightarrow0} \frac{\frac{f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)}{\Delta x}-\frac{f(x)-f(x-\Delta x)}{\Delta x}}{\Delta x}$$
Then think about limit properties and the geometric and algebraic definitions of derivative, and you should have a pretty good start.